# Bonding of Lithium and Argon

Tags: elements, reactivity, noble-gases

I saw a meme that was joking around about Lithium and Argon bonding (see pic below). It got me wondering: Can Lithium and Argon bond in any circumstance?

[image: You Made Lithium React With Argon?" alt="You Made Lithium React With Argon?]

Comment: https://www.nature.com/articles/srep16675

Comment: @orthocresol The world LiAr is all throughout that paper. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no joke; a gas-phase lithium-argon diatomic molecule does exist. However, it (and about two dozen other di-atoms having various elements bonded to the argon) is considered to be bound only by a van der Waals interaction. See the list of diatomic van der Waals molecules [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon_compounds)

Comment: Can you justify your statement ? Do you have a reference ?

Comment: Did I not link to the Wikipedia article? They cite many references for the claimed molecules.

Answer (score 0):

Argon is a noble gas. This means that it does not simply "bond" with anything. These gases have a very strong resistance to joining with other atoms. So, to answer your question, no, you can not bond argon and lithium under any circumstances. Anyone who says they have done so is a LiAr.

Also, since lithium is highly reactive and flammable and argon is used in neon, I would not suggest trying to combine these two without a proper location and gear.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at orthocresol's link in the comments to the OP, and doing a search for noble gas chemistry and compounds. There are too many compounds to name, including LiAr.

Comment: Yes, as I said, it is a Noble gas so it will not simply bond, please point me out in the areas that I was misinformed on so that I can correct myself. Thanks.

Comment: @Nathanael the comment is meant to be helpful. The first lines in the abstract of the paper: "High pressure can fundamentally alter the bonding patterns of chemical elements. Its effects include stimulating elements thought to be 'inactive' to form unexpectedly stable compounds with unusual chemical and physical properties." If you take the [stackexchange tour](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) you'll see that SE is a little different than other sites. Welcome!

Comment: "High pressure can fundamentally alter the bonding patterns of chemical elements. Its effects include stimulating elements thought to be “inactive” to form unexpectedly stable compounds with unusual chemical and physical properties."- From the abstract, ortho sent.

Comment: @NilayGhosh and uhoh Thank you for your input, I forgot about pressure. I appreciate your help! :D It's nice to know when I messed up on something so I can go and relearn it! Thanks again!

Comment: @airhuff, if I sounded offenseful I apologize, I could have worded that differently. Since I overlooked this, how much force (estimated) would be needed to change the bonding patterns? Thanks again and sorry if I came out rude!

Comment: @Nathanael you can avoid loss of the reputation points by deleting this answer. It's the way stackexchange works; the idea is to leave a set of questions and helpful answers for the benefit of future readers as well as for the OP (original poster) of the question. Down votes aren't towards the poster of a question or answer, they are votes on the content only, so never take them personally even when they feel like it. *Theoretically* we should all be working together to learn from each other and leave a nice set of Q&A's behind for future readers, and eventually for AI when it takes over ;)

Comment: I do not understand "and Argon is used in neon".

Comment: @Nilay I accidentally approved your flag - I shouldn't have. Flags should not be used to indicate wrong content, that's what voting is for.